# Arduino littleBits

Tags: arduino, ide

I am trying to download code to my littleBits Arduino module on IDE software.  I am not able to find the port whenever I am trying to download the image to the board. Is this an internal issue, or an issue with my Arduino board?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the arduino serial driver is properly installed in device manager. If arduino serial port is available in Ports then you can download program through IDE
For visual help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4HqXAmV_Ock

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have proper drivers for your board. In Arduino IDE make sure you are selecting the proper target ie, littleBits Arduino board.

If you are using the Linux system you can use dmesg to see if your system detected the device properly.

If you are using windows system use device manager to make sure your device is properly connected.

Answer (score 0):

Has it ever worked?  Did it work for a while then stop?

Reason I ask, I had a problem where the Little Bit suddenly stopped accepting new code.  Whenever I tried to download, the Arduino IDE started reporting *Unknown USB Device*.

Turned out, we had bricked the device.  I blogged my steps for recovery [here](http://ramblings.sagar.org/2016/04/you-cant-avoid-cruel-realities-of.html).

Answer (score 0):

- Check tools>ports and see if any are available, try them all, (check
  while the board is connected)
- if none are available check device manager under com ports there should be your device listed if not the you need to reinstall the drivers.
- also check if the board is connected correctly (i.e. the connection cord is working properly)